# MySQL import wizard isn't importing the COMPLETE data

Tags: mysql, database, csv, mysql-workbench, sql-import-wizard

I used MySQL workbench's import wizard to import data from a csv file. The import was successful but not all the data rows were imported. My csv file contains 271,117 rows but only 270,396 were imported successfully. 721 rows were not imported.
There was no error message at all but this is no good, right? How do I rectify this issue?

Comment: Save imported data to another CSV. Compare source and exported files, find skipped rows and see why they weren't imported. PS. I think that wizard uses either REPLACE or IGNORE modifier for LOAD FILE - import the data using a query and see does some errors occures..

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. But I converted my csv data to JSON using https://csvjson.com/
Afterwards I validated the JSON using https://jsonlint.com/.

Btw when you convert the data to JSON remember the first row needs to be the column names :)

Then inside of mySQL workbench select the table --> Table Data Import Wizard --> select the JSON file.